# Reactivate Save Site As Template without Designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, site-template

Is there a workaround to setting `SaveSiteAsTemplateEnabled` to true without SharePoint designer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes , This can be achieved using the powershell commands .

in SharePoint 2013 Publishing Site by default the **Save site as Template** is not enabled and we can go to this option directly through url directly :

/_layouts/savetmpl.aspx

Or

/_layouts/15/savetmpl.aspx

But this also doesn't work in SharePoint 2013 if its a publishing site or the Publishing features are activated in the site.

so we should activate SaveSiteAsTemplateEnabled property for the Site using below powershell commands:

```
Get a reference to the target site

$web = Get-SPWeb http://site/Publishing

Update the property bage value and set it  to the string value “true”

$web.AllProperties[“SaveSiteAsTemplateEnabled”] = “true”

Commit the property change to server

$web.Update()
```

Now if we navigate to the Save site as a template page using the URL directly it will show fine and it will allow us to save the site as a template which stores a copy in the Solution gallery of the site collection.